# Where can I access documentation for old versions of Mathematica?

Tags: documentation

Some documentation of functions available in old versions of *Mathematica* (and old packages) is available online, e.g.
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/Vertices.html

Is there anywhere I can search through the documentation for all functions for a specific older version of *Mathematica* (specifically v.9)?

Seems like it should exist but I am having trouble finding it.

Comment: All available [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it was right under my nose

Comment: Related: "[Making a working copy of the legacy documentation for version 5 inside new versions of Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5779835/590388)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: oohhh! Neat link contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the links have changed to [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/). Here's the new in version X pages:

- [New in version 6](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn60.html)
- [New in version 7](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn70.html)
- [New in version 8](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn80.html)
- [New in version 9](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn90.html)

Comment: ciao's link is a better portal than any of these

Comment: lol, just saw that!

Comment: You should accept @ciao's comment :)